# Autodesk Forge Viewer - Adding Custom Text Input

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk

Currently in Forge's Documentation on Viewer Extension, the only control that can be added is a button. Is there a way to add custom one such as Text Input box?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

For such tasks, please use docking panel.
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/reference/javascript/dockingpanel/
https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/viewer/extensions/panel